# WCF security binding, Ntlm vs NTLM

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, ntlm

If I set my app.config with Ntlm as follows:

```
<security mode="Transport">
   <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
   <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
</security>
```

I get this error:

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'.

If I switch my app.config to NTML as follows:

```
<security mode="Transport">
   <transport clientCredentialType="NTLM" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
   <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
</security>
```

I get the following error:

> The value of the property 'clientCredentialType' cannot be parsed. The error is: The enumeration value must be one of the following: None, Basic, Digest, Ntlm, Windows, Certificate, InheritedFromHost.

I don't know what to do here, one fix to leads to an error, and that errors fix leads to the initial error ... Thanks for the help

Comment: If your website has the "negotiate" provider - try using "Windows" instead of "Ntlm"

Comment: For anyone else looking, just take note that clientCredentialType values *are* case sensitive

Comment: Paul, all xml config is case sensitive